# CocoaAsyncSocket UDP Simple Server & Client

Tags: ios, objective-c, udp, cocoaasyncsocket

I'm trying to start off and create a simple UDP server and client using CocoaASyncSocket. I've pretty much replicated the code in the examples from [here](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket/tree/master/Examples/GCD)

**UPDATE:**

I've tried running the provided examples but they don't seem to work with the host address + port that I provided. What would I fill in for those (on the client end) if my client + server are on the same wifi?

**My Server:**

```
-(void)startServer{
    udpSocket = [[GCDAsyncUdpSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

    NSError *error = nil;

    if (![udpSocket bindToPort:PORT error:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Error starting server (bind): %@", error);
        return;
    }
    if (![udpSocket beginReceiving:&error])
    {
        [udpSocket close];
        NSLog(@"Error starting server (recv): %@", error);
        return;
    }

    NSLog(@"Udp Echo server started on %@:%i",[udpSocket localHost_IPv4],[udpSocket localPort]);

    isRunning = YES;

}
```

**My Client:**

```
-(void)setupSocket{
    udpSocket = [[GCDAsyncUdpSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

    NSError *error = nil;


    if (![udpSocket bindToPort:HOST_PORT error:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Error binding: %@", error);
        return;
    }
    if (![udpSocket beginReceiving:&error])
    {
        [udpSocket close];
        NSLog(@"Error receiving: %@", error);
        return;
    }

    NSLog(@"ready");
}

- (IBAction)send:(id)sender
{

    NSString *msg = @"testerrrr";

    NSData *data = [msg dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [udpSocket sendData:data toHost:HOST_IP port:HOST_PORT withTimeout:-1 tag:0];
    NSLog(@"sent message to server");
}
```

I don't believe that my issue is in the initialization of the server or the socket, but perhaps in what my chosen IP + PORT's are. Right now I am running the server on iOS simulator and the client on a real device. When sending data from the device, I can see that packets are going out, but none are being received by the server.

I have it set up to bind port 1234, and that the client sends it to the server's address which I got from "whatismyip.com". I also tried reversing the roles, but still no success.

Additionally, when I tried sending data to itself (server -> server for example), that worked, but between the two no luck!

This seems like a pretty straightforward task but haven't been able to get it to work. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

As I initially suspected, the issue was with the address i was entering on behalf of the client. The rule to thumb is:

1. If S + C are running on same device. Use "localhost" as host address
2. If S + C are running on different devices, but on same wifi connection. Do IFConfig on the server and use the IP found there.
3. If S + C are running on different devices and do not share the same connection, you need to forward the port from your router to your computer.

Hope that helps!